# I want to display latest post in marquee

Tags: functions

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Breaking News
*/

function rif_breaking_news(){
        
        
?>
<div class="breaking_news_box" style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2E8B57;bottom: 0;color: #CCCCCC;direction: ltr;height: 32px;left: 0;min-width: 600px;position: fixed;width: 100%;z-index: 99935;" id="breaking_news">     
    <b class="breaking_head">Latest News:</b>
    <ul style="margin:4px;">

        
        <marquee 
        behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="3" scrolldelay="60" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
        <?php $latest = get_posts('numberposts=5'.'&offset='.'&cat=13'); foreach( $latest as $post ): ?>
        
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </marquee>
    
    </ul>
</div>

<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer','rif_breaking_news');
function rif_css_fileLink(){
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'css/style.css" >';
}
add_action('wp_head','rif_css_fileLink');
?>
```

Comment: Just posting a code block isn't a good way to write a question. If you need help modifying this code it would be useful to have some idea how far you'd got on your own, what change and where you think you'd need to make, and what the result of that was i.e. why it didn't work. Or if this is your attempt and it doesn't work then more details of how it doesn't work - what you were hoping it would do, what it actually does, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a local loop, so template functions won't behave as expected without a `$post` parameter:

```
<marquee>
    <?php $latest = get_posts('numberposts=5&cat=13'); foreach( $latest as $_post ) : ?>
    
        <a href="<?php the_permalink( $_post ); ?>"><?= get_the_title( $_post ); ?></a> &nbsp; &nbsp;

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</marquee>
```